# TestNG run/debug from IDEA cannot load main class files

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, testng

I have inherited some Selenium TestNG tests which I can run with no problem via 'mvn test' but when I try to run/debug inside IDEA I receive an instant error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files
```

In my own projects I have xml test suites and I keep my /main empty. I can run tests easily with either command line and inside IDEA.
However, this project structure is different from one I developed myself. Here I have test classes in /test/java directory but all PageObject classes, helpers and such in /main/java. There is no xml suites (I am not sure how it is even working and if it is possible to run certain test class). See picture below.

[image: Project structure]

The question is: how to make those tests run/debug inside IDEA?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your run configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

As dumb as it sounds I have been passing a parameter to Firefox binary within '' instead of "" resulting 
    -Dbinary='C:/Program Files/...' 
to be interpreted as 
    -Dbinary =C:/Program 
with remaining string treated as class.